# Which AWS instance suitable for ImageMagick processing?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, imagemagick

I am currently using aws t1 micro instances. Recently, I just installed the textcleaner script from Fred's ImageMagick Scripts. I realised that the textcleaner process takes a long time to complete.

If I were about to upgrade my instance, which instance should I choose? The one with more CPU-processing power or more graphic-processing power?

Comment: Just a little word of advice from someone who regularly processes 60,000+ images per day... have a look at GNU Parallel - it can make phenomenal throughput improvements and is actually pretty simple to use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just found this on serverFault:

https://serverfault.com/questions/519329/efficient-server-configuration-for-imagemagick

> In other words, look for machines with minimal amount of memory
>   (4-8GB) and many cores or even many CPUs. If you're using Amazon, then
>   High-CPU Instances is what you're looking for. For very large load, it
>   may be good idea to look at cluster instances.